# Searching for architecture approach for converting Kafka Message to other formats

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices, messaging, templating

We're using Kafka as a broker which takes notifications from different message sources and then routes them to one or more target apps like Slack or E-Mail. Having such an approach it is necessary to convert the Kafka message into different output formats like JSON or E-Mail before they are sent to the apps.

I thought of having Microservices with SpringBoot at the target ends which takes the message from Kafka, converts it using one of the common template languages like Velocity or Freemarker into the target format and then forwards the converted result to the given target app.

Would you agree with such an approach or are there better ways, some caveats or even no-gos to do it this way? What about performance? Any experience in this?

Thanks for your honest assessment.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a single serialization format and let each service deserialize the payload for their use case? Templating with something like Velocity or Freemarker seems like a specific concern independent of the data used to populate the template. Maybe focus on broadcasting the raw data.